# snowflake pivot column scanning table 2 times problem issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below query as shown below written in snowflake. Now I see there are limitations on Pivot functionality. This is the below query written by me. The functionality of the query is looking good.

```
with assettbl as (
    select * from asset
    where assettype='HAZARD' 
    and groupname='UNDC' 
    and status='COMMISSIONED'),
assetspectbl as(
    select assetnum,
         distance_back,
                    req_clearance,
                    pls_cadd_model,
                    als_survey_date,
                    weather_case,
                    last_work_date,
                    mad,
                    distrib_company,
                    risk_ass_date,
                    temp_mit_in_place
               from  (
                    select assetnum, 
                           alnvalue,
                           assetattrid
                    from assetspec
)
pivot 
(
   min(alnvalue)
   for assetattrid in ('DISTANCE-BACK'  ,
'REQ-C' ,
'PLS-CADD'   ,
'ALS-SURVEY-DATE'  ,
'WEATHER' ,
'LAST-WORK-DT' ,
'MADDERY'  ,
'DISTRIB-COMP' ,
'RISK-ASS'   ,
'TEMP-MIT'  
 )
) AS p(assetnum,
       distance_back,
       req_clearance,
       pls_cadd_model,
       als_survey_date,
       weather_case,
       last_work_date,
       mad,
       distrib_company,
       risk_ass_date,
       temp_mit_in_place)
order by assetnum),
locationspectbl as (select classstructureid,
                        location, 
                        structure_from,
                        structure_to 
                from (
                        select  classstructureid,
                                location, 
                                alnvalue,
                                assetattrid
                from locationspec
                     where assetattrid in ('ST_FROM' ,'ST_TO' 
               )
)
pivot 
(
   min(alnvalue)
   for assetattrid in ('ST_FROM',
'ST_TO' 
                      
 )
) AS p(classstructureid,
       location,
       structure_from,
       structure_to)
order by location),
locationtbl as(
            select * from location
            ),
categorytbl as (
            select classstructureid,
                   location, 
                   structure_category_from 
            from
            (
              select  classstructureid,
                      location, 
                      alnvalue,
                      assetattrid as assetattrid
                from locationspec
                where assetattrid='LINE-STR'
)
pivot 
(
   min(alnvalue)
   for assetattrid  in('LINE-STR') 
)
 AS p(classstructureid,
      location,
      structure_category_from
      )
order by location),
categorytbl1 as(select classstructureid,
                    location, 
                    structure_category_to 
               from (
                     select  classstructureid,location, 
                             alnvalue,
                             assetattrid as assetattrid
                       from locationspec
                      where assetattrid='LINE-STR'
)
pivot 
(
   min(alnvalue)
   for assetattrid  in('LINE-STR') 
 )
 AS p(classstructureid,
      location,
      structure_category_to)
order by location),
main_sql as (select  assettbl.assetnum as _key_asset_id
                    ,assettbl.assetnum as "Asset Number"
                    ,assettbl.status as "Asset Status"
                    ,assettbl.tphazstatus as "Hazard Status"
                    ,locationtbl.location as "Location"
                    ,locationtbl.service_area as "Service Area"
                    ,locationtbl.site as "Site"
                    ,locationtbl.region as "Region"
                    ,assetspectbl.distance_back as "Distance (m) in from back structure"
                    ,assetspectbl.req_clearance as "Required clearance"
                    ,assetspectbl.pls_cadd_model as "PLS CADD model"
                    ,assetspectbl.als_survey_date as "ALS Survey Date"
                    ,assetspectbl.weather_case as "Weather Case"
                    ,assetspectbl.last_work_date as "Last Work Date"
                    ,assetspectbl.mad as "MAD"
                    ,assetspectbl.distrib_company as "Distribution Company"
                    ,assetspectbl.risk_ass_date as "Risk Assessment Date"
                    ,assetspectbl.temp_mit_in_place as "Temporary Mitigation in place"
                    ,locationspectbl.structure_from as "Structure From"
                    ,categorytbl.structure_category_from as "Structure Category From"
                    ,locationspectbl.structure_to as "Structure To"
                    ,categorytbl1.structure_category_to as "Structure Category To"
 from assettbl 
 left join assetspectbl on assettbl.assetnum=assetspectbl.assetnum
 left join locationtbl on assettbl.location=locationtbl .location
 left join locationspectbl on locationspectbl.location=assettbl.location
 left join categorytbl on  category.location=locationspectbl.structure_from
 left join categorytbl1 on categorytbl1 .location=locationspectbl.structure_to
           )
select * from main_sql;
```

The problem in the above query is I have to scan and parse the category table for 2 times. Is there any best way to scan the category table only once.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: if you are scanning the same table twice move the code into a CTE, which you have shown you know how it use. On the other hand, sometimes it's faster (based on filters or columns) to process a table twice, that do it once and do more than it needed as the overlap of the usages is not the great. As a side note, this is very unfocused and messy SQL to asking a vague question

Comment: also you should not have ORDER BY 's in your CTE's they just slow things down.

Comment: Hello Sir, Thanks for your prompt response. Can you please give an example of CTE of moving the code into one CTE instead of 2 as there are 2 CTE for categorytbl and categorytbl1. The categorytbl alias is for getting 'ST_FROM' category and categorytbl1 is for 'ST_TO' category. can you please give me an example? . I will remove the order by from the above sql.

Answer (score 0):

okey, so all this time later I have rewritten your SQL:

```
with assettbl as (
    select * 
    from asset
    where assettype='HAZARD' 
        and groupname='UNDC' 
        and status='COMMISSIONED'
), assetspectbl as(
    select 
        assetnum,
        distance_back,
        req_clearance,
        pls_cadd_model,
        als_survey_date,
        weather_case,
        last_work_date,
        mad,
        distrib_company,
        risk_ass_date,
        temp_mit_in_place
   from  (
        select 
            assetnum, 
            alnvalue,
            assetattrid
        from assetspec
    )
    pivot ( min(alnvalue) for assetattrid in ('DISTANCE-BACK'  ,
                'REQ-C' ,
                'PLS-CADD'   ,
                'ALS-SURVEY-DATE'  ,
                'WEATHER' ,
                'LAST-WORK-DT' ,
                'MADDERY'  ,
                'DISTRIB-COMP' ,
                'RISK-ASS'   ,
                'TEMP-MIT'  
                 )
    ) AS p(assetnum, distance_back, req_clearance, pls_cadd_model, als_survey_date,
           weather_case, last_work_date, mad, distrib_company, risk_ass_date, temp_mit_in_place)
    --order by assetnum
), locationspectbl as (
    select 
        classstructureid,
        location, 
        structure_from,
        structure_to 
    from (
        select  
            classstructureid,
            location, 
            alnvalue,
            assetattrid
        from locationspec
        where assetattrid in ('ST_FROM' ,'ST_TO' )
    )
    pivot ( min(alnvalue) for assetattrid in ('ST_FROM', 'ST_TO' ) ) AS p(classstructureid, location, structure_from, structure_to)
    --order by location
), locationtbl as (
    select * 
    from location
), categorytbl as (
    select 
        classstructureid,
        location, 
        structure_category_from 
    from (
        select  
            classstructureid,
            location, 
            alnvalue,
            assetattrid as assetattrid
        from locationspec
        where assetattrid = 'LINE-STR'
    )
    pivot ( min(alnvalue) for assetattrid  in('LINE-STR') ) AS p(classstructureid, location, structure_category_from )
    --order by location
), categorytbl1 as(
    select 
        classstructureid,
        location, 
        structure_category_to 
    from (
        select  
            classstructureid,
            location, 
            alnvalue,
            assetattrid as assetattrid
        from locationspec
        where assetattrid = 'LINE-STR'
    )
    pivot ( min(alnvalue) for assetattrid in('LINE-STR') ) AS p(classstructureid, location, structure_category_to)
    --order by location
), main_sql as (
    select  
        assettbl.assetnum as _key_asset_id
        ,assettbl.assetnum as "Asset Number"
        ,assettbl.status as "Asset Status"
        ,assettbl.tphazstatus as "Hazard Status"
        ,locationtbl.location as "Location"
        ,locationtbl.service_area as "Service Area"
        ,locationtbl.site as "Site"
        ,locationtbl.region as "Region"
        ,assetspectbl.distance_back as "Distance (m) in from back structure"
        ,assetspectbl.req_clearance as "Required clearance"
        ,assetspectbl.pls_cadd_model as "PLS CADD model"
        ,assetspectbl.als_survey_date as "ALS Survey Date"
        ,assetspectbl.weather_case as "Weather Case"
        ,assetspectbl.last_work_date as "Last Work Date"
        ,assetspectbl.mad as "MAD"
        ,assetspectbl.distrib_company as "Distribution Company"
        ,assetspectbl.risk_ass_date as "Risk Assessment Date"
        ,assetspectbl.temp_mit_in_place as "Temporary Mitigation in place"
        ,locationspectbl.structure_from as "Structure From"
        ,categorytbl.structure_category_from as "Structure Category From"
        ,locationspectbl.structure_to as "Structure To"
        ,categorytbl1.structure_category_to as "Structure Category To"
    from assettbl 
    left join assetspectbl 
        on assettbl.assetnum = assetspectbl.assetnum
    left join locationtbl 
        on assettbl.location = locationtbl.location
    left join locationspectbl 
        on locationspectbl.location = assettbl.location
    left join categorytbl 
        on  category.location = locationspectbl.structure_from
    left join categorytbl1 
        on categorytbl1.location = locationspectbl.structure_to
)
select * 
from main_sql;
```

and I finally see your question:

you have noticed the the CTE `categorytbl`

```
categorytbl as (
    select 
        classstructureid,
        location, 
        structure_category_from 
    from (
        select  
            classstructureid,
            location, 
            alnvalue,
            assetattrid as assetattrid
        from locationspec
        where assetattrid = 'LINE-STR'
    )
    pivot ( min(alnvalue) for assetattrid  in('LINE-STR') ) AS p(classstructureid, location, structure_category_from )
    --order by location
)
```

is 100% the same as  `categorytbl1`

except you have one parameter different. ether just use the one CTE and handle the name difference, OR make the second just refer to the first like:

```
categorytbl as (
    select 
        classstructureid,
        location, 
        structure_category_from 
    from (
        select  
            classstructureid,
            location, 
            alnvalue,
            assetattrid as assetattrid
        from locationspec
        where assetattrid = 'LINE-STR'
    )
    pivot ( min(alnvalue) for assetattrid  in('LINE-STR') ) AS p(classstructureid, location, structure_category_from )
    --order by location
), categorytbl1 as(
    select 
        classstructureid,
        location, 
        structure_category_from as structure_category_to 
    from categorytbl
)
```

Comment: Hello Sir, Thank you for your prompt response wonderful suggestion on this.  I am extremely grateful to you for giving the suggestion. Yes its great solution. just use one CTE by adding the different column into the above and remove the second CTE.

Comment: ```
categorytbl as (
    select 
  classstructureid,
  location, 
  structure_category_from,structure_category_to
 from (
  select  
   classstructureid,
   location, 
   alnvalue,
   assetattrid as assetattrid
  from locationspec
  where assetattrid = 'LINE-STR'
 )
 pivot ( min(alnvalue) for assetattrid  in('LINE-STR') ) AS p(classstructureid, location, structure_category_from )
 --order by location
),